# Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1', 'org.freedesktop.login1'

Tags: linux, systemd

Даже не знаю, как описать вопрос. systemd не стартует logind по непонятным пока что мне причинам.

Немного укороченный лог:

```
11:08:35 deployer dbus[680]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.login1': timed out
11:08:35 deployer dbus[680]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out
11:08:35 deployer systemd-logind[812]: Failed to enable subscription: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out
11:08:35 deployer systemd-logind[812]: Failed to fully start up daemon: Connection timed out
11:08:35 deployer node_exporter[676]: time="2019-09-11T11:08:35+03:00" level=error msg="ERROR: systemd collector failed after 21.041678s: couldn't get units: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out" source="collector.go:136"
11:08:35 deployer systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
11:08:35 deployer systemd[1]: Failed to start Login Service.
11:08:35 deployer systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Unit entered failed state.
11:08:35 deployer systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
11:08:35 deployer systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Service has no hold-off time, scheduling restart.
11:08:35 deployer systemd[1]: Stopped Login Service.
11:08:35 deployer systemd[1]: Starting Login Service...
```